# Expanding transparent circle animation on a LongClickListener event

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

In my main activity I've set up 2 `ImageView` views with `OnLongClickListener` evenets bound to them. Now I'd like to add the animation of a transparent red circle expanding from the middle of those views while the event takes place.

I've also added `OnTouchListener` events on those views calling `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` field to detect the release of the click for other functionality, I expect this to be used to make the circle disappear instantly when the click is released.

So when the user clicks on the view and holds it, the circle starts expanding up to a certain point in a slow animated fashion and it disappears when he releases.

How would I go about doing this? It was too specific to find anything on my own, so I had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and found a simple solution using the `animate().scaleXBy`and `animate().scaleYBy` methods.

```
ivRedCircle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ivRedCircle1.animate().scaleXBy(4).setDuration(2500);
ivRedCircle1.animate().scaleYBy(4).setDuration(2500);
```

`ivRedCircle1` is a reference to one of the views to which I want this animation applied to. To be exact, this is the picture of a red circle placed on top of another `ImageView`. Initially set invisible, when the `onLongClick` event is triggered, the image appears and starts expanding 4 times in size. 2500 is the duration of 2500 milliseconds or 2.5 seconds, that's how long it takes to grow 4 times in size.

After that, in the `onTouchListener` event when the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is triggered, I've added this piece of code to make it retract and disappear with the `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` method.

```
ivRedCircle1.animate().scaleXBy(-4).setDuration(1000);
ivRedCircle1.animate().scaleYBy(-4).setDuration(1000);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ivRedCircle1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}, 1000);
```

It's important to place `setVisibility` inside the `run()` method with the delay exact to the duration of the animation, in order to make it disappear as it retracts to its original size.